# C Passing structures as arguments

Tags: c, struct, aggregate-functions

I am making a program in which passing structure as arguments but i am having error

```
void main()
{
    struct strucintcal
    {     
        char name[20];
        int numb;
        float amt;
    } xyz;

    void intcal(struct strucintcal);

    printf("\n Enter Customer Name: ");
    gets(xyz.name);

    printf("\nEnter Customer Nuber: ");
    scanf("%d",&xyz.numb);

    printf("\nEnter principal aomunt: ");
    scanf("%f", &xyz.amt);

    intcal(xyz);

    getch();
}
```

linker Error : Undefined symbol _intcal

Comment: Show us your function definition and **don't use** `gets()` function anymore

Comment: You need to compile & link the file containing the `intcal` as well.

Comment: Note that `    void intcal(struct strucintcal);` is a function prototype. It doesn't define the function itself. It's done with same syntax except the `;` after `)` that must be `{` and then the function body followed by `}`

Answer (score 3):

You need to define `void intcal(struct strucintcal);`:

```
void intcal(struct strucintcal s)
{
    s.field...
}
```

Also, it's generally better to pass structures by pointer:

```
void intcal(struct strucintcal *s)
{
    s->field...
}
```

Comment: The formal type `strucintcal` is going to have to move as well.

Comment: @WhozCraig One thing at a time, I suppose. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have void intcal(struct strucintcal) defined however you haven't told it to do anything! Usually when you define a function with no body before it's used you declare it afterwards. So what you need to do is define intcal somewhere else:

```
void intcal(struct strucintcal s) {
    //Do your calculations
}
```

Also as the person above me said, passing structures with pointers is usually a better idea! Also I recommend moving the defenition outside of main() and same with you're structure. That allows all areas of the program to access it (including outside functions).